# Why is my Taylor series for calculating cosine inaccurate for some inputs?

Tags: c, taylor-series

I am evaluating value of cos(x) using the Taylor's series which calculates the series up to n terms where n is entered by user.

I am getting correct output for some values (correct up to 4 decimal places, which is very nice) but I am also getting hugely erroneous outputs for some values of x.
Please see my code and tell me what is exactly going wrong here.

input x=0.5 n=10, output cos(x) = 0.877583, which is correct.

input x=-0.8 n=7, output cos(x) = 0.696707, again correct.

input x=5 n=10, output cos(x) =  0.283625, correct.

input: x=10    n=10 output: cos(x) = -34.438612 huge inaccuracy

```
double x, t=1,s=1;
int i,n;

printf("Enter x\n");
scanf("%lf",&x);
printf("Enter n");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    t*=(-x*x)/((2*(i-1)+2)*(2*(i-1)+1));
    s+=t;
     }

printf("\n %lf \n", s);
```

Why is my Taylor series for calculating cosine inaccurate for some inputs?

Comment: Taylor series converges slowly. Better to memoize a trig table for, say 0°  <= x <= 90°, then normalize any input angle to fit in that range.

Comment: Because the range of a Taylor polynomial of any fixed degree, like of any polynomial, is unbounded. As the argument grows, a 20th degree polynomial will sooner or later shoot to infinity really really fast.

Comment: Plot the graph at https://www.geogebra.org/m/s9SkCsvC and see where exactly a Taylor approximation stops being a good idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is in mathematics rather than in programming.

Answer (score 3):

It has been a while, but I am pretty sure that the domain of x is {0..2} for this calculation, as x is in radians.
A test you can add inside your loop is:

```
if (s < -1 || s > 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Range error!: %le\n", s);
    exit(1);
}
```

Also, if you have a unix-y system, here is your program in bc, which does not rely on float point approximation:

```
scale=20
define t(x,n) {
 auto i, s, t
 s = 1
 t = 1
 for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    t*=(-x*x)/((2*(i-1)+2)*(2*(i-1)+1))
    s+=t
    if (s < -1 || s > 1) {
        "range error!\n"; return s
    }
 }
 return s
}
```

You can run this interactively with bc *filename*, then type in your examples like t(8, 10).

As for whether the sequences converge for all values of x; my math is probably not good enough to answer that.   That is why I chose programming, math is hard.
However, here is a cosine definition from an old systems bclib.b:

```
define  c(x) {
        auto a, b, c, d, e, g, y;
        y = - x*x;
        a = 1;
        b = 1;
        c = b;
        d = 1;
        e = 1;
        for (a=2; 1 == 1; a += 2) {
                b *= y;
                c = c*a*(a-1) +b;
                d *= a*(a-1);
                g = c/d;
                if (g == e) return (g);  
                e = g;
        }
}
```

Which is slightly different from yours, yet does seem to work for any range of input.   So, you might want to take a look at what is different....
(note that in bc, the variable *scale* holds the precision the calculator is working in; so c(8,10) is scale=10; c(8)

Comment: doesn't maclaurin series for cosine converges for all real x?

Comment: @Abhay estimate the error you get when you cut off the series at Nth member.

Comment: @mevets will it be a good idea to do x modulo 2pi before evaluating the series? because cos has a period of 2pi